# What exactly is new [] doing in a class vs struct?

Tags: c#, class, struct, indexer

```
MyClass[] CLASS = new MyClass[5];
int[] STRUCT = new int[5];
```

What exactly is new [] doing for a class vs a struct. Apparently the struct has some overloaded static index that causes it to run the default constructor of the struct. However the new [] for a class appears to do nothing but make space to initialize an instance of a class. How do I overload the static behavior of the class to also run the default constructor. I know how to use for loops and other methods of accomplishing this. My question is very specific to what is going on underneath the new []. I understand that a struct needs a default value. But doesn't a non-nullable class also need a default value which is why it gives an error when you try to use it? Or is this telling me that all classes are actually nullable?

Comment: @CuongLe An array of what? An array of absolutely nothing? When I create an int array it creates an array of 0s because it is a `struct` but when I create a `class` array it creates absolutely nothing but space hence the null error upon trying to use it. The struct calls the default constructor but if a class index calls absolutely nothing then what is it actually creating? Is there a way to overload the static index like it is behaving in the struct? As far as I am concerned new CLASS[] does nothing and the actual array is created in the for loop or whatever method is used to initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the default constructor of `struct` isn't run. What happens instead is that in the `struct` case, the memory is initialized to zero. What this means depends on the data type. E.g., a reference field (like a class or a string) becomes `null`, numeric fields become `0`, boolean fields become `false`, etc.

This differs very much from how classes work. This is why with the initialization of the `class` array, you see `null` values. Basically, it comes down to this. An "empty" `class` variable (or array in your case) becomes `null`. However, when you have an "empty" `struct`, you already have something valid. However, it is initialized as empty.

The easiest way to see this is when you e.g. have an `int` field in a class. This works basically the same way. When you add an `int` field to a class, you are not required to initialize it. When you don't initialize it, it gets the value `0` by default. `struct`'s work the same way in this regard.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471.aspx for a bit more information.

A few more things to note (answer to the question in the comments):

- Classes are always nullable. This means that the only way to initialize the array is to create a loop and initialize a new instance for every item in the array;
- The default constructor doesn't apply to structs, because they aren't allowed to have a default constructor. If you try to compile the following code snippet, you will get a compilation error telling you this:

  ```
  struct MyStruct
  {
      public MyStruct()
      {
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Are all classes nullable? What is the difference between a nullable class and a non-nullable class if I can't make a default value for an array of the class without using a for loop or some other structure? Also if the default constructor of struct isn't run then when is it ran?

Comment: But doesn't all structs have a hidden default constructor? Does this mean the code that makes Boolean false and numeric 0 and classes null inaccessible to the programmer and actually part of the language structure itself? For example suppose just for the sake of curiosity I wanted to create a simple value type with it's own unique default value I wouldn't be able to do this in c#?

Comment: `struct`'s do not really have a default constructor. C# makes it look like they have a default constructor (in that you can do constructor chaining by adding `: this()` to your constructor), but they don't really exist.